# Decoded transaction hex without enough signatures?

Tags: transactions, multi-signature

Can someone show me the output of decoderawtransaction when the transaction requires multiple signatures, but it hasn't been signed by enough people, and the transaction was created using createrawtransaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tips: 14y7Zx9V19AJHD8AKDYa46WnKH1Ey7atd5

{
    "txid" : "0a7bc048ce3bebbd77dd16a5113978284a424eae766b680bb4a258322701d227",
    "version" : 1,
    "locktime" : 0,
    "vin" : [
        {
            "txid" : "551cc8a4953515b845ed2ea37037877be32118d81259cb8b36d7d42a1ae83b29",
            "vout" : 1,
            "scriptSig" : {
                "asm" : "",
                "hex" : ""
            },
            "sequence" : 4294967295
        }
    ],
    "vout" : [
        {
            "value" : 0.00010000,
            "n" : 0,
            "scriptPubKey" : {
                "asm" : "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 b36797fc263fc01d374ace37a0ea30c444fbfa73 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
                "hex" : "76a914b36797fc263fc01d374ace37a0ea30c444fbfa7388ac",
                "reqSigs" : 1,
                "type" : "pubkeyhash",
                "addresses" : [
                    "1HMc49uNVcw9yxREZ2NztL8wAb9dg4n8tN"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "value" : 0.00010000,
            "n" : 1,
            "scriptPubKey" : {
                "asm" : "OP_HASH160 b2e1d360c89521feda58dc194b324a7cd442e48b OP_EQUAL",
                "hex" : "a914b2e1d360c89521feda58dc194b324a7cd442e48b87",
                "reqSigs" : 1,
                "type" : "scripthash",
                "addresses" : [
                    "3HzrjLKjMmH5chsadUWxr7DJzhRf771V2r"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}

I did not give a scriptsig when I created the transaction.
If I had given a scriptsig, then it would appear in this decoded transaction.

The only time you should give a scriptsig (I think) is when you are creating multiple transactions that depend on eachother, and you are not broadcasting them.